# Omnikey 5421 generic card command interface not working for Mifare plus SL1

Tags: windows, mifare, omnikey

I'm trying to switch a Mifare Plus card into SL1 mode using an Omnikey 5421, however using the "Generic card command" interface as instructed by the documentation does not seem to work (card does not return any kind of output except 0x9000 which seems to be only an ACK that the command was sent succesfully - there should be additionaly bytes in the response before 0x90 0x00 which come from the chip itself).

The sequence is sent using SCardTransmit:

0xFF 0xA0 0x00 0x07 0x03 0x01 0x00 0x01 - enter generic session - returns 0x9000

... additional commands using documentation:

0xFF 0xA0 0x00 0x05 6+n 01 00 F3 00 00 64 + Mifare+ command 00  - returns 0x9000 whatever the command, even if invalid Mifare+ commands

0xFF 0xA0 0x00 0x07 0x03 0x01 0x00 0x02 - exit generic session - returns 0x9000 still

The only commands that seem to work are enter and exit, any other command that I send in between does not seem to have any effect, including RATS, Writeperso or Commitperso. When I add the 00 Le byte at the end the return code is 0x6400 instead of 0x9000, even though the docs say that Le byte should be appended when issuing Mifare+ commands.

All other operations work ok once the cards is personalized in SL1 mode (read, write, authenticate). I can already switch the card to SL1 mode using android NFC, so it does not seem to be a problem with the algorithm or the card.

I've tried to use command from the PC/SC part 3 documentation, but the return code is "not supported", so it seems that only this mechanism of transparent channel is available to issue 14443A commands.

Answer (score 1):

In SL0 and SL3, You may directly call the Plus command via Generic Card Command.

"generic session" should be for SL1 to accept Plus command(as by default it goes to mifare classic mode)